# Spark: RDD from multiple different local files

Tags: java, apache-spark

*Is there any way to create one RDD from multiple different txt (or binary) files located at local file system?*

I have 5 workers. Each worker contains file `file:///tmp/names.txt`, but `names.txt` is different on each worker. I need to create RDD that will contain all names from all workers. My code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String namesFilePath = "file:///tmp/names.txt";
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<String> names = spark.read().textFile(namesFilePath).cache();
        // PROBLEM: return only names from one of the workers!
        System.out.println("All names: " + names.collectAsList());
        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot rely on the fact that spark will schedule your work on all nodes.

Comment: @user6910411 just ignore the link in the comment

Comment: I would go to HDFS instead of local file systems. You can't be sure that all files would be read

Comment: @MFARID just imagine, billions of small files inside HDFS. No, I need to find you solution or use another distributed file system with Spark instead of HDFS\

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Maybe, but you don't really want to do that.

It might be possible to hack low level tools like `preferredLocations` to create dummy `RDD` and load data directly inside a task, but it is clearly going against Spark architecture and not using built-in readers.

It would also assume lack of failures, which is a correct assumption in the deployment scenario, where using Spark has limited applications.

So essentially you would trade most of makes Spark useful:

- Resilience.
- Ability to scale out with minimal user intervention.
- Transparent computation model.
- Ability to utilize resources in a cost efficient manner.

and left with micromanaging and highly defensive programming (`preferredLocations` are exactly that, preferred not guaranteed) without any help from the framework itself.

Comment: I'm sure I want to do that. I will have hundreds of billions small I/O operations on local file system, and Spark is not good for that. As output I will have millions of small files locally, and I have to reduce files by  key from local file systems

Comment: could you please provide me with more details about hack?

Comment: _and Spark is not good for that_ - that is probably the main point. Why not use tools that _is_ good in that?